# Constraints and Limits for Window functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for any limits where Window functions like RANK() doesn't work for specific fields in the table of specific type.
When I ranked by partitioning the int specific fields the ranking is done correctly but when I tried to rank the bigint specific field the ranking is done for every tuple in table as 1 and doesn't ranked according to partition mentioned .

```
SELECT
  category, 
  price,
  pid,
  RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY price ) AS myrank 
FROM 
  products;
```

FYI,
The code above doesn't rank correctly.
price is of type bigint

If I partition using category which is of type int it works well......
But as same instead of category I partitoned using price but it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make much sense to be using `RANK` without an `ORDER BY` clause.  Either of the two following queries would be sensible uses of `RANK`:

```sql
SELECT category, price, pid, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY price) myrank
FROM products;

SELECT category, price, pid, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY price) myrank
FROM products;
```

The first query would assign a rank to each record across the entire table based on the price.  The second query would also assign a rank based on price, but it would maintain separate ranks for each category.